# Webhook trigger for jenkins remotefile multibranch pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch configuration job, which I have created for using the remote jenkins file plugin, I have git repo in which I have the "jenkinsfile" named as customjenkins Now I am trying to configure the job in such a way that when ever a change is done to the "jenkinfile" the build should trigger,  but in my case the top build is only triggered but the job with repo inside doesnt trigger and only can be done manually, please see the picture below for better understanding. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here
[image]

[image]